# Memoization not function correctly

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
pB :: [(Integer, Integer, Integer)] -> Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
pB lst x y
    | screenList lst x y /= -1 = lst
    | abs x > y = lst++[(x, y, 0)]
    | y == 1 = lst++[(x, y, 1)]
    | otherwise = lst++newEls
  where
    newEls = (pB lst x (y-1))++(pB lst (x-1) (y-1))++(pB lst (x+1) (y-1))

getFirst :: (Integer, Integer, Integer) -> Integer
getFirst (x, _, _) = x

getSecond :: (Integer, Integer, Integer) -> Integer
getSecond (_, y, _) = y

getThird :: (Integer, Integer, Integer) -> Integer
getThird (_, _, z) = z

screenList :: [(Integer, Integer, Integer)] -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
screenList [] _ _ = -1
screenList lst x y
    | getFirst leader == x && getSecond leader == y = getThird leader
    | otherwise = screenList (tail lst) x y
  where
    leader = head lst
```

Which, by running an inefficient solution of (Ie: One which didn't keep track of values which had already been computed) returned the value 51 for input x = 0, y = 5. Now, running this with input [] 0 5 I should be able to find (0,5,51) in the output, which unfortunately I don't.

I have been looking at it for a few hours, but can't seem to understand where I'm going wrong.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

EDIT: Inefficient version:

```
nPB :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
nPB x y
    | abs x > y = 0
    | y == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = (nPB x (y-1)) + (nPB (x-1) (y-1)) + (nPB (x+1) (y-1))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? By the way, note that (1) you should be using at least the `Data.List` functions to avoid having to write stuff like `screenList` using explicit recursion, thus making the code easier to understand; and (2) a list-based implementation will not be very efficient whatever you do, as list lookups have O(n) complexity.

Comment: If you want memoization then consider using one of the many packages on Hackage that provides automatic memoization.

Answer (score 3):

**Administrivia**

It is rather hard to tell what you are asking, but I gather that you have a function that is terribly slow and you have tried to manually memoize this function.  I don't think anyone is trying to understand your attempt, so if this question is primarily about manually memoizing a function and/or fixing your code then please submit another question that more clearly outlines its design.

In the remainder of this question I will show you how to use monad-memo and memo-trie to memoize the function you've named `nPB`.

**Memoizing `nPB` with monad-memo**

The `nPB` function is a prime target for memoization.  This is readily apparent by glancing at it's three recursive calls.  The below small benchmark takes 1 second to run, lets see if we can do better.

```
nPB :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
nPB x y
    | abs x > y = 0
    | y == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = (nPB x (y-1)) + (nPB (x-1) (y-1)) + (nPB (x+1) (y-1))

main = print (nPB 10 20)
```

In a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515025/edit-distance-algorithm-in-haskell-performance-tuning/5515379#5515379) I used the [monad-memo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo) package.  Using monad-memo involves making your function monadic, which is syntactically more invasive than the other packages I know of, but I've always have good performance.

To use the package you simply:

- make sure to call one of the `memo` functions with the target function as the first parameter.
- Be sure to `return` your final result
- Adjust your type signatures to include a constraint of `MonadMemo` and adjust the result to be some monad `m`.
- Run the function with `startEvalMemo`

The code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.Memo

nPB :: (MonadMemo (Integer,Integer) Integer m) => Integer -> Integer -> m Integer
nPB x y
    | abs x > y = return 0
    | y == 1 = return 1
    | otherwise = do
        t1 <- for2 memo nPB x (y-1)
        t2 <- for2 memo nPB (x-1) (y-1)
        t3 <- for2 memo nPB (x+1) (y-1)
        return (t1+t2+t3)

main = print (startEvalMemo $ nPB 10 20)
```

**Memoizing `nPB` with MemoTrie**

The most common Haskell memoization package in use is [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie).  This is also a syntactically cleaner memoization package as it does not requires any sort of monad, but it currently suffers from a slight performance issue when using Integer as we shall soon see (bug has been reported, use of `Int` and other types seems fine).

There is much less to do to use MemoTrie, just replace your recursive calls with `memoN` where `N` is the number of arguments:

```
import Data.MemoTrie

nPB :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
nPB x y
    | abs x > y = 0
    | y == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = (memo2 nPB x (y-1)) + (memo2 nPB (x-1) (y-1)) + (memo2 nPB (x+1) (y-1))

main = print (nPB 10 20)
```

**Performance**

Using a type of `Integer` the performance is:

```
$ ghc original.hs -O2 && time ./original
8533660    
real    0m1.047s

$ ghc monad-memo.hs -O2 && time ./monad-memo
8533660
real    0m0.002s

$ ghc memotrie.hs -O2 && time ./memotrie
8533660
real    0m0.331s
```

And using `Int`:

```
$ ghc original.hs -O2 && time ./original
8533660
real    0m0.190s

$ ghc monad-memo.hs -O2 && time ./monad-memo
8533660
real    0m0.002s

$ ghc memotrie.hs -O2 && time ./memotrie
8533660    
real    0m0.002s
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this question is about memoization. I'm not sure how you are trying to implement this, but there are two "standard" ways of memoizing functions: use one of the libraries, or explicitly memoize the data yourself.

```
import Data.Function.Memoize (memoize)
import Data.MemoTrie (memo2)
import Data.Map (fromList, (!))
import System.Environment

test0 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
test0 x y
       | abs x > y = 0
       | y == 1 = 1
       | otherwise = (test0 x (y-1)) + (test0 (x-1) (y-1)) + (test0 (x+1) (y-1))

test1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
test1 = memoize test0

test2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
test2 = memo2 test0
```

But it doesn't look like the memo libraries I tried are able to handle this, or I did something wrong, I've never really used these libraries: (The test code is at the bottom - these results from `x,y = 0,18`)

```
test0 : Total time  9.06s 
test1 : Total time  9.08s
test2 : Total time 32.78s
```

So lets try manual memoization. The principle is simple: construct your domain in such a way that later elements only require the value of earlier elements. This is very simple here since your function always recurses on `y-1`, so you just need to build the domain moving up the rows. Then write a function which looks up earlier values in a table (here I use `Data.Map.Map`), and map over the domain:

```
test3 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
test3 x' y' = m ! (x', y')
  where
    xs = concat [ map (flip (,) y) [-x + x' .. x + x'] | (x, y) <- zip [y', y' - 1 .. 1] [1..]]

    m = fromList [ ((x,y), go x y) | (x,y) <- xs]

    go x y
       | abs x > y = 0
       | y == 1 = 1
       | otherwise = m ! (x, y-1) + m ! (x-1, y-1) + m ! (x+1, y-1)
```

I actually construct a domain that is much than needed for simplicity, but the performance penalty is small since the extra domain is all 0 anyways. Taking a look at the performance, it is almost instant (`Total time 0.02s`). Even with `x,y=0,1000` it still only takes 7 seconds. Although with large inputs you end up wasting a lot of time on GC.

---

```
-- usage: ghc --make -O2 -rtsopts Main.hs && Main n x y +RTS -sstderr
main = do 
  [n, x, y] <- getArgs
  print $ (d !! (read n)) x y
    where d = [test0, test1, test2, test3]
```

---

Here is the version written with `memoFix2`. Better performance than any other versions.

```
test4 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
test4 = memoFix2 go where 
  go r x y
       | abs x > y = 0
       | y == 1 = 1
       | otherwise = (r x (y-1)) + (r (x-1) (y-1)) + (r (x+1) (y-1))
```

Comment: `memo2 test0` seems to be wrong to me. Can you show the full code?

Comment: Applying a memoization function to `test0` only memoizes the final result, it does not cause `test0` to use memoization for its own recursion. You need to rewrite `test0` to call its memoized version when recursing.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I tried that, it takes even longer than the other versions! I was extremely surprised. The version with memoFix allocates `6,480,001,160 bytes` while the version with explicit sharing `188,708 bytes`. The profiling report shows that there are millions of calls to `go` - so again, I am either doing something wrong, or the library can't handle this case. @is73 The code you see before you is all the code there is.

Comment: I think your problem is that you used `memoFix` rather than `memoFix2`, which means it only memoizes with *one* argument of the function.  All that does is memorize one partially applied closure per x value, which still has to redo all its real work every time you apply it to the remaining y, since all the real work requires having access to y.

Comment: Also, now that I've looked up what `memo2` does, I think you could fix your first attempt by letting `test0` call `test2` when recursing, instead of itself directly.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ok, I see what you mean. I guess I should read the documentation occasionally. Both of your fixes do the trick: with `memoFix2` the function executes about twice as fast as `test3`; and `test0` executes much faster - but still about 4 times slower than `test3`- and spends only 5% of the time garbage collected, lower than any other version. I'm guessing the reason it is slower is because it converts integers to and from lists of `Bool`.